# Cannot see script result

Tags: javascript, draw

Hi I have following script, but when I run it in Chrome I dont see the result.
What did I miss? What do I have to add to html to see my results.

```js
<script>
noStroke();
var leftX = 145;
var rightX = 274;
var sunRadius = 100;
var draw = function() {
    background(184, 236, 255);
    fill(255, 170, 0);
    ellipse(200, 100, sunRadius, sunRadius);
// clouds
   fill(255, 255, 255);
    // left cloud
    ellipse(leftX, 150, 126, 97);
    ellipse(leftX+62, 150, 70, 60);
    ellipse(leftX-62, 150, 70, 60);
    // right cloud
    ellipse(rightX, 100, 126, 97);
    ellipse(rightX+62, 100, 70, 60);
    ellipse(rightX-62, 100, 70, 60);
    leftX--;
    rightX++;
    sunRadius+=2;
};
</script>
```

Comment: Any console errors? What is `noStroke();`?

Comment: A function named `draw()` is defined, but not called in the code you show.  Also, where do all these other functions come from `fill()`, `ellipse()`, `background()`, `noStroke()`, etc...  Those are not part of standard Javascript.  And, are there errors showing in the debug console?

Comment: The code is from khanacademy, I copied it to my file on pc to see if it can run but no result https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming/animation-basics/p/challenge-parting-clouds

Comment: @AhmetAlibašić Can you include a JSFiddle of your entire code? I suspect you are not including ProcessingJS library.

Answer (score 0):

1. Whatever `noStroke` (and other functions like `fill` and `background) are, make sure they're defined in your code, or else the rest of the function won't execute.
2. The reason that your function isn't being callled... Is because you're not calling it.

Add a call to `draw` after the function is declared. The end of the code should look like:

```
    leftX--;
    rightX++;
    sunRadius+=2;
};
draw(); //Actually run the function
```

Answer (score 0):

I think ellipse is new for canvas.  I found a function for backwards compatibility on [github](https://gist.github.com/floriancargoet/20cede87a76b4073177f).

```js
var can = document.getElementById('can');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

var leftX = 145;
var rightX = 274;
var sunRadius = 100;

draw();

function draw() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(184, 236, 255)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ellipse(200, 100, sunRadius, sunRadius);
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 170, 0)";
  ctx.fill();

  // clouds
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
  // left cloud
  ctx.beginPath();
  ellipse(leftX, 150, 126, 97);
  ellipse(leftX + 62, 150, 70, 60);
  ellipse(leftX - 62, 150, 70, 60);
  ctx.fill();
  // right cloud
  ctx.beginPath();
  ellipse(rightX, 100, 126, 97);
  ellipse(rightX + 62, 100, 70, 60);
  ellipse(rightX - 62, 100, 70, 60);
  ctx.fill();
  leftX--;
  rightX++;
  sunRadius += 2;
};

function ellipse(cx, cy, w, h) {
  var rx = w / 2;
  var ry = h / 2;
  var rot = 0;
  var aStart = 0;
  var aEnd = Math.PI * 2;
  florianEllipse(ctx, cx, cy, rx, ry, rot, aStart, aEnd);
}

function florianEllipse(context, cx, cy, rx, ry, rot, aStart, aEnd){
  context.save();
  context.translate(cx, cy);
  context.rotate(rot);
  context.translate(-rx, -ry);
  
  context.scale(rx, ry);
  context.arc(1, 1, 1, aStart, aEnd, false);
  context.restore();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="can" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```